# Jquery manipulating number of elements with given pattern of id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code below hides a section if radio button is unchecked.

```
if ($('#Items_0__Suffix:checked').val() === 'No') {
        $('#section0').hide();
    }
```

Now if we have multiple items, what is the succinct way to write code rather than code like below:

```
if ($('#Items_0__Suffix:checked').val() === 'No') {
        $('#section0').hide();
    }
if ($('#Items_1__Suffix:checked').val() === 'No') {
            $('#section0').hide();
        }
```

Comment: It looks like your selectors use an iteratorable pattern. Run it through a loop (`var i` for index) and `$('#Items_'+i+'__Suffix:checked').val()`

Comment: What does html structure look like? Probably no need for ID's for this at all

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sequence of the checkbox id starts with zero and has the corresponding element whose id also starts with zero, you can use `jquery starts with` selector and use `jquery index()` to figure out the element to show/hide.

```
$("[id^=Items_]").on("click",function()
{        
   var index = $(this).index();
   !$(this).is(":checked") ? 
   $('#section' + index).hide() : $('#section' + index).show();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/97bo2vyb/2/

Comment: note this assumes items are siblings ... simple tweak to index items only regardless of structure https://jsfiddle.net/21wbujc4/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a for loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= amountOfButtons; i++) {
    if ($('#Items_' + i + '__Suffix:checked').val() === 'No') {
        $('#section0').hide();
    }
}
```

Or even using [Regex](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) in your selectors could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and pass in the context.  Reuse the remaining code.  Example:

```
Var doWork = function(context) {
       If ($(context).val() == 'No') {
            $('#section0').hide();
       }
 }
```

This way you can call the same function and code for reuse without having to duplicate it each time.